# Function logic explanation

Tags: python, function

I came across this exercise on code wars that left me stumped for a couple days. The exercise is to write a function that takes in a list of directions. The function is then supposed to 'reduce' the directions down to simpler directions. For example, if you are to travel 'NORTH','SOUTH','EAST','NORTH' ; the directions would be reduced to 'EAST', 'NORTH' due to traveling north and then south again would be putting you at the same location. The same 'reduction' process needs to happen for all the variations:
N <--> S , W <--> E

I ended up having to find code that was already tested and worked as the solution to the problem. My issue is that I don't exactly understand the logic behind it. I have gone ahead  and put the code below with a few comments on my thought process behind it what is happening in the code.  I

I am just looking for a bit more clarity on this particle code. Thanks!

```
def dirReduc(arr):
    
    #create a dictionary with all the possible combinations that need to be 'reduced'
    opposites = {'NORTH':'SOUTH', 'SOUTH':'NORTH', 'EAST':'WEST', 'WEST':'EAST'} 
    
    #create an empty list to store the valid directions that are not reduced. 
    new_list = []
    
    #iterate through the list of items that has been passed to the function.
    for item in arr:
        #This is where i get lost. I dont understand the logic behind this. 
        #you check to see if the new list and the corrosponding item in the dictionary are equal to an empty list??
        if new_list and opposites[item] == new_list[-1]:
            new_list.pop()
        else:
            new_list.append(item)
    return new_list
```

Comment: "`if new_list`" checks that `new_list` is not empty (meaning we've moved at least once). If that's the case, then `new_list[-1]` (the last element) is the last move we made. So `opposites[item] == new_list[-1]` checks if the move we're about to make is the opposite of the move we just made, and if so we undo the last move instead of adding a new move.

Comment: You might be getting tripped up by the `and`. In fact, that conditional's order of operations resolves to `if (new_list) and (opposites[item] == new_list[-1]):` - the `and` operator has lower precedence than the `==` operator.

Comment: So the if statement gets passed over the first go around due to the list being empty and the else statement populates the list with the first item from the passed argument. Then on the second iteration the if statement sees that the list is no longer empty and then uses a comparison operator to see if the dictionary value is  equal to the the last index of the new list?

Answer (score 0):

So, your question is 'you check to see if the new list and the corrosponding item in the dictionary are equal to an empty list??'

The if-statement consists of two parts with an 'and' between them.

- The first 'if new_list' returns *false* if the new list is empty and
  will not evaluate the statement after the 'and', but will instead
  forward to the else-part to add the item to the new list.
- If the new list is not empty AND the current item is opposite to the
  previous item (opposites[item] == new_list[-1]) the previous item is
  removed from the new list.
- If the new list not empty AND the current item is NOT opposite to the
  previous item, the code will forward to the else-part to add the item
  to the new list.